# how to use asp core tag helpers to update part of view?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I know how to use partial view with ajax to update only part of page (view)
ex:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("All", "All", new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    UpdateTargetId = "st",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
})
<div id="st">

</div>
```

but I try second method using code below and it's not work, it's show the data in another page

```
<a asp-action="All"  asp-controller="Albums"  
 data-target="Album" id="aUpdate" >All</a>
    <div id="Album">       
   </div>
```

did I do things wrong or it's not possible to use the second way to update part of page?

Comment: You can just add all the necessary `data-` attributes (e.g. `data_ajax = "true", data_ajax_method = "GET", data_ajax_mode = "replace", data_ajax_update = "#st"` etc), but its obsolete. Just use the jquery ajax methods which give you more flexibility and you do not need `jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.js` e.g. `$(yourlink).click(function() { $('#st').load(yourUrl); });`

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear to me.